# Can someone translate this charm?

Tags: translation

We found this charm in a box of buttons, and I'm curious what it means... For all I know it may not be Chinese, but it looks like it.

I tried translating it using the Google Translate app... While it saw the shape of the charm, it was unable to come up with any matching translation. I tried to draw it in manually as well, but it did not recognize my pictogram.

I'm not really sure how else to go about trying to figure out the translation myself. (The little roundish thing at the top is just the hanger to put a chain through).

[image]

Alternatively, if anyone knows this character from a different language, feel free to point that out too.

Comment: _If_ this is meant to be a Chinese character, it is `笑` which means 'laughter, smile'.

Comment: As to off-topic, as stated in the question, I did attempt to find out what this character is myself, ... failing to be able to do so, I figured I would ask the experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the character for laughter in Chinese 笑'xiao'

Comment: Well, "laughter" *does* sound like the kind of word one might wear as a charm.

Comment: Yeah it looks indeed like 笑, or at least a version made by someone who can't write Chinese.

Comment: That is not "笑", that is more like "䒨"

Comment: @Red2awn Or it's just flipped over...